# equivalent command to start/end time in sharpPcap

Tags: command, pcap, sharppcap

What is the equivalent command in sharpPcap to the wireshark command:

```
capinfos -a -e <pcap name>
```

This command returns the value of the start and the end time of the recording.

Thank You!

Comment: That command returns the value of the time stamp of the first packet in the file and the time stamp of the last packet in the file.  Those are *not* necessarily the time the capture was started and the time the capture was ended - the first packet may arrive after the capture is started and the last packet may arrive before the capture is ended.  Not all capture file formats record the start and end time of the capture (pcap format doesn't support it, and pcapng format allows a program do so but I don't know of any software that does so).

Comment: So what do you recommend in this case?
For me it's okay if it's not exactly the exact time.
I'm looking for something similar to the command I wrote, but in the C# language.
Because it seems unnecessary to me to run console through .net core, for a line of code that works well with wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what do you recommend in this case? For me it's okay if it's not exactly the exact time. I'm looking for something similar to the command I wrote, but in the C# language.

Open the capture file and read all the packets.  Save the time stamps of the first packet you read and the last packet you read.  That's how capinfos does it.